# Linux Mint Instant Resume When Suspend

Tags: linux-mint, suspend

When I suspend, my desktop computer immediately resumes and the power and fans don't switch off. It is different from when I try to hibernate : there, it shuts down for a second, then resumes as well.

But my goal is to make at least suspend work.

So here is my log from /var/log/syslog :

Mar  7 00:23:15 Aaren systemd[1]: Starting Suspend...

Mar  7 00:23:15 Aaren systemd-sleep[5607]: Failed to connect to non-global ctrl_ifname: (nil)  error: No such file or directory

Mar  7 00:23:15 Aaren systemd-sleep[5608]: /lib/systemd/system-sleep/wpasupplicant failed with error code 255.

Mar  7 00:23:15 Aaren systemd-sleep[5607]: Suspending system...

Mar  7 00:23:15 Aaren kernel: [  611.316339] PM: suspend entry (deep)

Mar  7 00:23:23 Aaren kernel: [  611.316342] PM: Syncing filesystems ... done.

Mar  7 00:23:23 Aaren kernel: [  611.562735] Freezing user space processes ... 
(elapsed 0.002 seconds) done.

Mar  7 00:23:23 Aaren kernel: [  611.564787] OOM killer disabled.

Mar  7 00:23:23 Aaren kernel: [  611.564787] Freezing remaining freezable 
tasks ... (elapsed 0.001 seconds) done.

Mar  7 00:23:23 Aaren kernel: [  611.566090] Suspending console(s) (use 
no_console_suspend to debug)

Mar  7 00:23:23 Aaren kernel: [  611.583330] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] Synchronizing SCSI cache

Mar  7 00:23:23 Aaren kernel: [  611.587395] sd 0:0:1:0: [sda] Synchronizing SCSI cache

Mar  7 00:23:23 Aaren kernel: [  611.587570] sd 0:0:1:0: [sda] Stopping disk

Mar  7 00:23:23 Aaren kernel: [  611.710016] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] Stopping disk

Mar  7 00:23:23 Aaren kernel: [  612.610985] snd_hdac_bus_update_rirb: 24 callbacks suppressed

Mar  7 00:23:23 Aaren kernel: [  612.610989] snd_hda_intel 0000:01:00.1: spurious response 0x233:0x0, last cmd=0x4f0900

Mar  7 00:23:23 Aaren kernel: [  612.610991] snd_hda_intel 0000:01:00.1: spurious response 0x40:0x0, last cmd=0x4f0900

Mar  7 00:23:23 Aaren kernel: [  612.610992] snd_hda_intel 0000:01:00.1: spurious response 0x0:0x0, last cmd=0x4f0900

Mar  7 00:23:23 Aaren kernel: [  612.610993] snd_hda_intel 0000:01:00.1: spurious response 0x40:0x0, last cmd=0x4f0900

Mar  7 00:23:23 Aaren kernel: [  612.610995] snd_hda_intel 0000:01:00.1: spurious response 0x0:0x0, last cmd=0x4f0900

Mar  7 00:23:23 Aaren kernel: [  612.610996] snd_hda_intel 0000:01:00.1: spurious response 0x0:0x0, last cmd=0x4f0900

Mar  7 00:23:23 Aaren kernel: [  612.610997] snd_hda_intel 0000:01:00.1: spurious response 0x40:0x0, last cmd=0x4f0900

Mar  7 00:23:23 Aaren kernel: [  612.610999] snd_hda_intel 0000:01:00.1: spurious response 0x0:0x0, last cmd=0x4f0900

Mar  7 00:23:23 Aaren kernel: [  612.611000] snd_hda_intel 0000:01:00.1: spurious response 0x0:0x0, last cmd=0x4f0900

Mar  7 00:23:23 Aaren kernel: [  612.611001] snd_hda_intel 0000:01:00.1: spurious response 0x0:0x0, last cmd=0x4f0900

Mar  7 00:23:23 Aaren kernel: [  612.883622] ACPI: Preparing to enter system sleep state S3

Mar  7 00:23:23 Aaren kernel: [  612.884036] PM: Saving platform NVS memory

Mar  7 00:23:23 Aaren kernel: [  612.884245] Disabling non-boot CPUs ...

Mar  7 00:23:23 Aaren kernel: [  612.899300] IRQ 25: no longer affine to CPU1

Mar  7 00:23:23 Aaren kernel: [  612.900308] smpboot: CPU 1 is now offline

Mar  7 00:23:23 Aaren kernel: [  612.923285] IRQ 26: no longer affine to CPU2

Mar  7 00:23:23 Aaren kernel: [  612.924293] smpboot: CPU 2 is now offline

Mar  7 00:23:23 Aaren kernel: [  612.951272] IRQ 27: no longer affine to CPU3

Mar  7 00:23:23 Aaren kernel: [  612.952501] smpboot: CPU 3 is now offline

Mar  7 00:23:23 Aaren kernel: [  612.971229] IRQ 16: no longer affine to CPU4

Mar  7 00:23:23 Aaren kernel: [  612.971236] IRQ 23: no longer affine to CPU4

Mar  7 00:23:23 Aaren kernel: [  612.971238] IRQ 28: no longer affine to CPU4

Mar  7 00:23:23 Aaren kernel: [  612.972245] smpboot: CPU 4 is now offline

Mar  7 00:23:23 Aaren kernel: [  612.996223] smpboot: CPU 5 is now offline

Mar  7 00:23:23 Aaren kernel: [  613.020204] smpboot: CPU 6 is now offline

Mar  7 00:23:23 Aaren kernel: [  613.044226] smpboot: CPU 7 is now offline

Mar  7 00:23:23 Aaren kernel: [  613.045350] ACPI: Low-level resume complete

Mar  7 00:23:23 Aaren kernel: [  613.045391] PM: Restoring platform NVS memory

Mar  7 00:23:23 Aaren kernel: [  613.045762] Enabling non-boot CPUs ...

Mar  7 00:23:23 Aaren kernel: [  613.045801] x86: Booting SMP configuration:

Mar  7 00:23:23 Aaren kernel: [  613.045802] smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 
1 APIC 0x2

Mar  7 00:23:23 Aaren kernel: [  613.048304]  cache: parent cpu1 should not be sleeping

Mar  7 00:23:23 Aaren kernel: [  613.048565] hpet: hpet3 irq 25 for MSI

Mar  7 00:23:23 Aaren kernel: [  613.048662] CPU1 is up

Something must be awakening it up. Can somebody enlighten me on this ? What's relevant in the log ?

Comment: I had a similar issue: For some reason a youtube video in a browser forced my laptop to wake up immediately (it no longer does - cannot explain why, though). To see if that could be your issue, close all browser windows.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, however this doesn't seem to be the source of the problem since even if no browser is active the problem is exactly the same :-(

Comment: Can you try with a liveUSB distro and see if that will work? In other words: Can we find a config that _does_ work on your hardware?

Comment: I have two hard drives on this computer : one with windows 10 and one with linux mint. the windows hard drive perfectly goes to sleep...